# Is it possible to change document.activeElement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, focus

Is it possible to programmatically change the value of the `document.activeElement` property in JavaScript?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

In IE, use the [`setActive()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536738%28VS.85%29.aspx) method of the element that you want to be the active element. In other browsers that support `activeElement`, you can use the `focus()` method of the element, so long as the element is capable of receiving the focus (form elements, editable elements, elements with `tabindex` set).

If you want to set the activeElement back to the default (the `<body>` element in most browsers), just call the active element's `blur()` method:

```
document.activeElement.blur();
```

Comment: Let's take the page at jquery.com as an example. When you enter the page and check document.activeElement in FireBug you get "<body class="jq-enhanced">". Then let's say that you change activeElement do some link element (<a>). How can you after that reset activeElement to the previous one (body). I can't do it using document.body.focus();

Comment: just remember to set tabindex="-1" for div elements

Comment: @g00fy: In what circumstances?

Comment: @TimDown when you want to focus on "non focusable" DOM nodes, like a div.
If `tabindex="-1"` is set in a regular tag, it can be focused with `.focus()`

Answer (score 36):

You can just [`.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.focus) the element you want and it'll be the new `document.activeElement`.

Comment: element.focus only has an effect in Chrome 55 if element.tabindex is defined. Divs by default do not have a tabindex, so by default div.focus() has no effect. At any time before calling focus, just set element.tabindex to some value, like '-1'. Then call element.focus. You will see that now element === document.activeElement, which now means that scroll keys like up/down will apply to the currently active element. Confusing!

Comment: Looks like it should be `tabIndex`

Comment: My activeElement was an iframe and this didn't work for me on Chrome 84. `.blur()` did though.