# Hide iPad keyboard when document body is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

How do you do this? I'm trying to get the iPad keyboard to hide when anything besides the input is clicked, however only one place on my website lets you click it and close the keyboard. It's just a standard

```
<div>Content</div>
```

Nothing special about it. No idea why only when this area is clicked will the keyboard close. I have plenty of other divs with the same styling. How do you make an iPad detect clicks in the body to close the keyboard? Is there some javascript that needs called?

I'd like an actual answer, but this will probably be closed before I get one. =(

My jquery does have something on focus and on blur, just the following:

```
    $('.input-text').on('focus', function() {
    $('#chat-slide').css({
        display: 'none'
    });
});
$('.input-text').on('blur', function() {
    $('#chat-slide').fadeIn(400);
});
```

Could this be making the keyboard not close?

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger something like this:[Change document.activeElement programmatically in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995524/change-document-activeelement-programmatically-in-javascript), most likely you have an active element which calls for this.

Comment: I do not, or I do not believe I do. The jquery on my site has something that is like this:

` $('.input-text').on('focus', function() {
        $('#chat-slide').css({
            display: 'none'
        });`

Answer (score 0):

Create a tiny invisible input field and focus on it programmatically, then remove it from the DOM. That way, no inputs are in focus anymore, and the OS will hide the keyboard