# How to Remove Focus after selecting Items from the Options in React Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have linked a code sandbox sample program [Sample Program](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-6j5syo?file=/demo.js), here we can notice once we select an item from the options still it is in a focused state, but I don't want it to get focused after selecting an option.

Can Someone please help on this to overcome this problem, Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: The focused state is working as intended. If you really don't want that feature though, you can try programmatically changing the focus on selection or changing focus to another element after selection.

Comment: @TrayDenney But I don't have any other element to get focused on, that's why I just need it to get focused out once it is selected.

Comment: Check this answer, it may help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995524/is-it-possible-to-change-document-activeelement-in-javascript

Comment: Everything is okay in the "Sample Program" instead of one thing. You're providing string as a value to `blurOnSelect` like `blurOnSelect="true"` you have to change it to `blurOnSelect={true}`, or just pass the props like this `blurOnSelect` it is shortcut from `blurOnSelect={true}`

Comment: @programmer Thanks man, the issue got resolved now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `blurOnSelect` prop to `Autocomplete`

```
<Autocomplete
    {...otherProps}
    blurOnSelect    // <== Here
/>
```

From `Mui` `Autocomplete` Documentation:
https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete :

> `blurOnSelect`:   'mouse' | 'touch' | bool
> Default: `false`

Comment: Not working, as true or any other option...

Comment: But it works on the demo of Dante1021, who ask the question !! https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-6j5syo?file=/demo.js , please add your demo to see what the problem.

Comment: I have some weird scenario, where I'm setting values between two dropdowns, and on first both dropdowns gets selected and I can move the values between, but after that initial clicks in any of both dropdowns, selected item(s) gets arial-selected="true"... If I don't find solution, I will make the solution with fully removing when value is sent to the other dropdown and vise-versa.